# What is the efficiency or other difference between these two queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, time-complexity, big-o

I downloaded the Yelp dataset and put it into MySQL as the datasets I have been working with have been too small to really have to consider efficiency. I am trying to unlearn or become aware of bad SQL habits which will cause problems with larger datasets.

Here are two ways of pulling exactly the same information out of the database:

```
USE yelp_db;

SELECT name, hours FROM business
LEFT JOIN hours
ON business.id = hours.business_id;
-- time taken 0,0025sec, 776071 rows returned

SELECT name, hours FROM
(SELECT name, id from business) AS b
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT hours, business_id from hours) AS h
ON b.id = h.business_id;
-- time taken 0,0015sec, 776071 rows returned
```

Here is a sample of the output:

```
John's Chinese BBQ Restaurant   NULL
Primal Brewery  Monday|16:00-22:00
Primal Brewery  Tuesday|16:00-22:00
Primal Brewery  Friday|12:00-23:00
```

The first method takes 3 lines but appears to be slightly slower than the second method which takes 5 lines.

Is either of these methods preferred in terms of efficiency or elegance and if so why?

Comment: Questions like this always require SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, as well as the EXPLAIN for each of the queries. Also, i would store from_hours and to_hours in separate columns.

Comment: I had a look, EXPLAIN and SHOW CREATE TABLE will be useful one day, big output however, if anyone is curious, schema is [here](https://www.yelp.com/dataset/documentation/sql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method is preferred for both performance and elegance -- your results not withstanding.

I'm a little suspicious about the timings.  I would expect more than a millisecond or two to return close to a million rows.

In any case, most versions of MySQL (the most recent might be exceptions) materialize subqueries.  This adds an additional layer of writes and reads to the query.  It can also prevent the use of indexes.

As for elegance, unnecessary subqueries do nothing for "elegance".  This might be a matter of opinion, but I'm guessing it is pretty wide-spread.

Comment: Thanks, am not sure exactly what _materialize subqueries_ means. Possibly the time would be more accurate in command line. Was sitting here longer than a fraction of a second, felt more like ten seconds, not sure why MySQL workbench is lying, assumed it was displaying time vs processing time.

Comment: PS - rerunning it in the command line mysql gives 2,20 sec for the first and 2,25 sec for the second.

Comment: @cardamom . . . I'm guessing that you are using a more recent version of MySQL that ignores the superfluous subqueries.  "Materialize" means that the subquery is run and stored essentially as a new table.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on @GordanLinoff 's excellent answer why you would see this difference.

If you ran them in the order shown simple caching of the data from the first one could explain the timing.  This caching can happen many places all the way down to the disc controllers.

The only way to test with useful results is to run many iterations and average the results after clearing all the caches.

Comment: @cardamom How long would it take to run each query as
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...... ?
  This will eliminate the 'effect' of Query Cache, if it is available.

Comment: @WilsonHauck -- That stops the compiled SQL statement from being cached-- nothing to do with the data.  I expect the data is being cached in (for example) the disk or raid controller. We are talking about a 10 ms difference in returning 3/4 of a million rows.

Comment: Thanks will have another look when I am back at the machine tomorrow. Sounds like you guys actually know what is going on under the hood of MySQL. Ok, interesting you can cancel that potential speed-up due to caching without closing MySQL and opening it again..

Comment: @cardamom  SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE will ALSO cause your system to 'read' the data and can be verified with EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE .....your query to get timing information.  Check in the 'rows' column of EXPLAIN results with and without SQL_NO_CACHE, please.

Comment: I reran both queries in the terminal 5 times with SQL_NO_CACHE on the first line after 'SELECT' and got 2.16, 2.16, 2.16, 2.17, 2.17 for the first and 2.23, 2.25, 2.19, 2.19, 2.20 for the second. Then the rows column of EXPLAIN.. for the 4 situations, each query with/without SQL_NO_CACHE is exactly the same: 147784, 5. They multiply to give almost the number of rows returned. Anyway, my question is answered - go with the first of these two. Sooner or later I'm sure I'll meet a query with way more significant time differences.